# Cuando Ejecuto mi proyecto sales este error

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Tengo un proyecto en xamarin con C#, ejecuto pero me sale este error

por favor ayuda

```
Código  Descripción Proyecto    Categoría de proyecto   Ruta de acceso  Archivo Línea   Columna Categoría   Origen  Estado suprimido    Herramienta
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
Nombre de archivo: 'System.Drawing.dll'
   en Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   en Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   Mi Asesor   1                       Compilación
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Drawning` no esta siendo totalemente soporta por XAMARIN para todas las plataformas segun la [lista de ensamblados disponibles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/)(esta al final de la pagina). Y según la nota:

> El soporte de System.Drawing se puede agregar a iOS y OS X utilizando
>   la biblioteca [sysdrawing-coregraphics](https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics)

Comment: A un que no fue exactamente la solución me enseñaste a interpretar el error y pude guiarme para buscar la solución.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeContrerasMuñoz sería buena idea agregaras una respuesta con tu solución para otros usuarios, saludos,